# How to Construct a unduplicate list?

Tags: java, thread-safety

I want to construct a unduplicated List using below code ,but something is wrong ,somebody says it's thread unsafe but  I don't get it ,so please give me some examples to prove it ,Thanks

```
class BadListHelper <E> {  
    public List<E> list = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<E>());  
    public synchronized boolean putIfAbsent(E x) {  
        boolean absent = !list.contains(x);  
        if (absent)  
            list.add(x);  
        return absent;  
    }  
}
```

Comment: What is "unduplicated List"? What is "something wrong"? What is expected and actual behaviour?

Comment: Why don't you use a `Set` ? More specifically a `LinkedHashSet` (If you want to maintain insertion order)?

Comment: @anacron it must be something like `LinkedHashSet` to ensure the order

Comment: I just don't understand  where the problem is  ,and  sorry I don't express myself clearly

Comment: I think your bug is that you believe this *somebody*.

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon - It is unsafe ... see my answer for an explanation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One problem with your code is that operations on your (exposed) `list` object, and the `putIfAbsent` method are synchronizing on different objects.  That means that `putIfAbsent` has a race-condition with respect to direct operations on `list`.

For example if you have two threads:

- thread A calls `helper.list.add(e)`
- thread B calls `helper.putIfAbsent(e)`

then you could end up with `e` in the list twice ... depending on the timing.

```
public synchronized boolean putIfAbsent(E x) {  
    boolean absent = !list.contains(x);  
    // <<--- the Thread A call could happen here.
    if (absent)  {
        list.add(x);  
    }
    return absent;  
}
```

Now admittedly, you would get the same effect if threads A and B both called `helper.list.add` directly.  However, the implied semantic of `putIfAbsent` is that it won't add an element that is already there ... and that is what it would do in the case above.

In fact, the implementation of `Collections.synchronizedList` returns a `List` object that synchronizes on itself.  So one fix is to change `putIfAbsent` to this:

```
public boolean putIfAbsent(E x) {  
    synchronized (list) {
        boolean absent = !list.contains(x);  
        if (absent) { 
            list.add(x);  
        }
        return absent;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks my friend,but "public synchronized boolean putIfAbsent(E x) " means another  thread can't call this method until  the current method done,so why there are multi-thread probleams?

Comment: The `synchronized` method call only excludes other method calls that synchronize on `this`.  That's a different object to `list`.  Therefore method calls on the `list` are not excluded.

Comment: I understand ,thanks @Stephen C